# NGINX lock directory listing

Tags: nginx

Currently, I'm working on some security recomendations on NGINX 1.12.2. I want to lock directory listing when calling to base URL. I can reproduce it using wget:

```sh
wget --spider -r --no-parent https://myownweb.com
```

This command returns all subdirectories. The only way to lock this I found is to restrict by user agent:

```
location / {
   if ($http_user_agent ~ (libwww|Wget|LWP|damnBot|BBBike|java|spider|crawl) ) {
       return 403;
   }
}
```

Is there another way to configure NGINX to avoid directory listing?

Answer (score 0):

Restrict(deny) Sub Directories

```
location ~ /(dir1|dir2|dir3) {
   deny all;
   return 404;
}
```

Instead of Restrict , Why Dont you deny ?

Comment: I don't want to deny all requests to directories, only want to avoid directory listing